# send dynamically generated file as email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, csv

I am currently allowing users to select certain parameters and based on those, I generate a csv file and push it as a download to the users.  e.g.

```
send_data <generated csv data>, :disposition => 'attachment' :type => 'text/csv'
```

Sometimes as the data becomes too large to compute, I do not want to make the users wait for the file to be pushed as download. I want to send this file as an attachment in an email.

I can send an email normally. I can send an already present file as an attachment. I do not want to save this file. I want to email it directly to the user.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@juanpastas - I did it the way you suggested. But that caused the file to be in displayed as a text in the email body.

This is how it appeared in the email.

> Content-Type: text/csv;
>   charset=UTF-8;
>   filename=data.csv
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename=data.csv
>   Content-ID: xyzxyz
>   [content of the csv file as text]

Then I included the message body and it worked.

```
mail(to: user.email, subject: 'XYZ', body: 'XYZ')
```

This caused the email to have the body and subject I provided and the file appeared as an attachment instead.

Comment: I'm trying to do this now. Can you show me the code you use for the `csv_data`? I'm trying to figure out how to refer to it. Currently when my app generates a csv file, it gets saved into the main directory where `app`, `db`, `config` lie. Do you use something different than this block: `CSV.open("my.csv", "w") do `

Answer (score 5):

I have not tested this, but this should work:

```
class YourMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def csv_mail(user, csv_data)
    attachments['a.csv'] = csv_data
    mail(to: user.email)

  end
end
```

And in your controller:

```
YourMailer.csv_mail(user, csv_data).deliver
```

See [attachments](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer%3a%3aBase-label-Attachments) and [inline attachments](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer%3a%3aBase-label-Inline+Attachments).